# What is a receiver in SWT (or GUI programming in general)?

Tags: object-oriented, gui

I see this notation used throughout documentation and discussions on SWT, but I've yet to see it actually defined. [The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259351/in-java-what-exactly-is-a-receiver-or-what-exactly-can-a-receiver-be) on Stack Overflow by [MarsAtomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305826/marsatomic) makes me think it is just the object that is associated with a method call, or is it more complex than this?

It seems to not be the case, but that is probably me not doing something right elsewhere in SWT ;).

Here is an example for a `layout` method of the `Composite` class:

```
public void layout (boolean changed) {
    checkWidget ();
    if (layout == null) return;
    layout (changed, false);
}

/**
 * If the receiver has a layout, asks the layout to <em>lay out</em>
 * (that is, set the size and location of) the receiver's children. 
 * If the changed argument is <code>true</code> the layout must not rely
 * on any information it has cached about its children. If it
 * is <code>false</code> the layout may (potentially) optimize the
 * work it is doing by assuming that none of the receiver's 
 * children has changed state since the last layout.
 ...
**/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object-oriented programming can be interpreted as [*message passing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing): objects are independent [actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) to which we can send messages (that is, we can invoke methods on that object). E.g. here I send the `panel` object a `layoutYourself` message:

```
panel.layoutYourself();
```

Some languages make this message sending more visible by using special message send operators. E.g.:

```
panel <- layoutYourself;
```

The receiver of the message, well, is called the *receiver*.

In languages like C++ or Java, method calls are much more like function calls than like message sends. However, the terminology “receiver” is still fairly widespread. A more function-oriented synonym is *invocant*: the thing on which you invoke the method.